# Changing tag cloud link to location

Tags: drupal

I am learning Drupal as I go and I am wondering if I can change a link coming from out of a tag cloud.

The link coming from the tag cloud goes to ...category/articles/locations/kittys

I would like it to go to the node tag at ...content/kittys

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the module you are using for this (tagadelic) and on where content/kittys leads to? Is that a node/view page?

Answer (score 1):

The assummed module you used for this, tagadelic, uses default taxonomy-paths for that.

So the answer is "yes" it can be changed. e.g. Forums (which are terms/tags in a taxonomy too) in a tagcloud will link to the forum home, not to the forum overview. This works because tagadelic uses [`taxonomy_term_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_path/6).

However, your question is a bit unclear about what (and why) you want to achieve this. What is "content/kitties"? Your question makes me believe you want to link to a node? Why? Tag-clouds represent tags, where the tag links to the list of posts within that tag.

That said, the easy way to change outgoing links is in the theme_function: to [override the theme function](http://drupal.org/node/341628).

```
/**
 * theme function that renders the HTML for the tags
 * @ingroup themable
 */
function my_custom_chees_puff_theme_tagadelic_weighted($terms) {
  $output = '';
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $output .= l($term->name, "/link/to/anywere", array(
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => "tagadelic level$term->weight",
        'rel' => 'tag',
        'title'  => $term->description,
        )
      )
    ) ." \n";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

The other option is to override the general "where should a tag-link-link-to" Drupalwide. As forementioned forum.module does, trough [`hook_term_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_term_path/6):

```
function my_cheesy_puffs_kitten_module_term_path($term) {
  return 'links/to/kittens/' . $term->tid;
}
```

Success! Bèr Kessels - Author and maintainer of Tagadelic :)